# Force RTL layout direction not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add RTL support in my app where layout direction should also change to RTL on force setting to RTL.

I have followed:

Set `minSdkVersion` to 19 ,
 Added `android:supportsRtl="true"` to application tag in `AndroidManifest.xml,`
 Switched left/right attributes to start/end

Followed [this link.](https://android.jlelse.eu/rtl-support-on-android-here-is-all-you-need-know-e13f2df512e2)

However, even when I use the "Force RTL Layout Direction", my app doesn't display the RTL layout. The system UI is flipped to RTL, and other apps also support RTL.

Is there anything else that need to be done?

Comment: You have to set your every layout direction to RTL as well.

Comment: Then it will have problem when we remove force layout  RTL in setting.Although i tried with that as well but not working

Comment: Do you add `android:supportsRtl="true"` to `<application>` tag in android manifest?

Answer (score 8):

in manifest.xml 
add android:supportsRtl="true" in tag

and in every activity add this line in onCreate method

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a much easier way to do the above changes without going through all the files and then doing it manually. Android Studio can do this for you.

> Just go to Android Studio > Refactor > Add RTL support where
>   possible…

or

> **try to use this link :**

[link](https://android.jlelse.eu/rtl-support-on-android-here-is-all-you-need-know-e13f2df512e2)

Comment: yeah followed that only, but it dint work, also provided the reason for same in my answer, mixpanel library was the reason,on updating its version everything worked smoothly

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason:

was using older version of mixpanel library
compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.6.0"

updated to latest version
compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.4.0"

hence ,check the libarary version,n update to latest.

Comment: How did you find out that library was the culprit?